# Completely regular spaces

Tags: general-topology

I need some help with the following question:

If $\mathbb X$ is a completely regulat space and $\mathcal B $ is a basis for the topology of $\mathbb X$ then there exists a family $\mathcal A$ of continuous functions going from $\mathbb X$ to [0,1] such that $\mathcal A$ separates points from closed sets in $\mathbb X$ and $|\mathcal A|\leq |\mathcal B|$.

$\mathcal A$ separates points from closed sets in $\mathbb X$ if for every point $x \in \mathbb X$ and every closed set $C\subseteq \mathbb X$ $\exists f \in \mathcal A$ such that $f(C)=0$ and $ f(x)=1$.

I used a similar idea to that of the proof of the Urysohn Metrization Theorem in Munkres but I'm having trouble defining the injection between $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$.

Comment: Could you make precise what you mean by "$\mathcal{A}$ separates points from closed sets"?

Answer (score 1):

Well, being completely regular means that you can separate points from closed sets for any fixed closed set and any point, right? So you can take a collection of 'nice' closed sets and points and make that work. For instance, you can take the collection of functions separating complements of basis elements from points chosen by taking one point in each basis element. This gives an injection into the set cross itself, which (for infinite sets) has the same cardinality as the original set, finte regular spaces are discrete.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Let $\mathscr{F}=\{\Bbb X\setminus B:B\in\mathscr{B}\}$. Show that for each $x\in X$ and each closed set $C$ such that $x\notin C$ there is an $F\in\mathscr{F}$ such that $C\subseteq F$ and $x\notin F$.